# Windows device password & Microsoft Account Password are different

Tags: windows, windows-10

So I have a Microsoft account on my devices (not local accounts). I changed my MS account password a while back but I still need to login to my devices using my old password, with no way to change it. The change password link in the settings just prompts me to change my MS account password again, which does NOT change my device passwords.

This is extremely frustrating, especially when networking shares are added to the mix. How do I change my device password ?!

Comment: You have to disconnect the accounts from your Microsoft Account, then link them to your Microsoft Account, in order to solve this problem.  I have had to do this many times on my own machines.